# Capture an object's internal scope for use in a function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, scope, closures

I have a customised vector container, and I'd like to give it a method which will return a list of all the elements which fulfil some condition. In fact, I've already done the hard part using some template tomfoolery which is outside the scope of this question; all I'd like to do from here is to simplify the syntax for the user.

To cut to the chase, my custom_vector<T> method's signature is:

```
custom_vector<int> where(std::function< bool (int) > predicate) const;
```

and a typical use case is:

```
// Find all the elements of myVector which lie between 2.71828 and 3.14159
custom_vector<int> theListOfElementsIWant =
    myVector.where([&myVector](int i) { return myVector.at(i)>2.71828 &&  myVector.at(i)<3.14159; });
```

Now this works absolutely fine and does exactly what I want but it's *ugly*; on that last line I had to type "myVector" four times, when it should be perfectly obvious after the first one which closure I want to work within. What I really want is to be able to type:

```
custom_vector<int> theListOfElementsIWant = 
    myVector.where([](int i) { return at(i)>2.71828 && at(i)<3.14159; });
```

or even better

```
custom_vector<int> theListOfElementsIWant = myVector.where(at(i)>2.71828 && at(i)<3.14159);
```

...but I can't figure out a way of achieving this or even getting close to it. Is there one, or am I just going to have to put up with doing a lot of typing?

As this doesn't seem like so outlandish a thing to want to do, I'd be even more pleased if someone can point me to way of doing this with the STL; I've looked hard but so far failed to find anything.

Comment: What does your `at()` method do? It look like you want to return a single element, or none.

Comment: maybe `where(std::function< bool (const custom_vector&, int) > predicate) const` or `where(std::function< bool (const iterator) > predicate) const`

Comment: @juanchopanza: `at(i)` simply returns the i'th element, so myVector.at(i) is exactly the same as saying myVector[i]. It's a Qt idiom ([] for non-const refererences, at() for const ones),

Comment: So, you can only possibly return zero or one element. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to pass element instead of index:

```
custom_vector<T> where(std::function<bool (const T&)> predicate) const;
```

with usage:

```
custom_vector<double> theListOfElementsIWant = 
    myVector.where([](double e) { return 2.71828 < d && d < 3.14159; });
```

Comment: Or even make `where` a function template so you don't need to build an `std::function` when one isn't needed.

Comment: Agree with you on the function operating on elements, not indices. However, why should `where` even be a member? Why not something like [`boost::filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html)?

Comment: @AmiTavory: I didn't want to do many changes to OP's prototype. I agree that it could be a free (template) function.

Comment: @AmiTavory, @juanchopanza: my first cut at this had `where` as a non-member function, but I found that it had to know the length of `myVector` in order to examine the full list, and making it a member seemed slightly more elegant than passing the size to it separately (matter of opinion, I know).

Comment: @EosPengwern: I expected that your container have a public `size` attribute (or `begin`/`end`), so you don't need to pass size.

Comment: @EosPengwern Not so sure about that. See here Scott Meyer's [How Nonmber Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197). Since `where` needs stuff that's available from other public methods (e.g., your size is just `distance(begin, end)`), it might be better to make it free.

Comment: @AmiTavory (and Jarod42): You're absolutely right, of course; I went off and thought about this a bit more, then reimplemented the whole thing as a non-member non-friend template function taking an element rather than an index (in just eight lines of code) and it works just as I want. I'll update my question to record what I actually did. Thank you!